# Terraform Snowflake doesn't allow to update/remove Snowflake task

Tags: terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I created a task in Snowflake with Terraform. It creates it as expected and the new Task shows in both Snowflake and the `.tfstate`. When I try and update the task (i.e. change the schedule) and apply the changes with `terraform apply`, Terraform tells me:

```
│ Error: error retrieving root task TASK_MO: failed to locate the root node of: []: sql: no rows in result set
│ 
│   with snowflake_task.load_from_s3["MO"],
│   on main.tf line 946, in resource "snowflake_task" "load_from_s3":
│  946: resource "snowflake_task" "load_from_s3" {
```

I did this just after creation, so no manual changes were made in Snowflake.
My assumption is that it can't find the actual task in Snowflake.

My resource

```
resource "snowflake_task" "load_from_s3" {
  for_each      = snowflake_stage.all
  name          = "TASK_${each.key}"
  database      = snowflake_database.database.name
  schema        = snowflake_schema.load_schemas["SRC"].name
  comment       = "Task to copy the ${each.key} messages from S3"
  schedule      = "USING CRON 0 7 * * * UTC"
  sql_statement = "COPY into ${snowflake_database.database.name}.${snowflake_schema.load_schemas["SRC"].name}.${each.key} from (select ${local.stages[each.key].fields}convert_timezone('UTC', current_timestamp)::timestamp_ntz,metadata$filename,metadata$file_row_number from @${snowflake_database.database.name}.${snowflake_schema.load_schemas["SRC"].name}.${each.key} (file_format => '${snowflake_database.database.name}.${snowflake_schema.load_schemas["SRC"].name}.${snowflake_file_format.generic.name}')) on_error=skip_file"
  enabled       = local.stages[each.key].is_enabled

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [after]
  }
}
```

The resource in `.tfstate`

```
        {
          "index_key": "MO",
          "schema_version": 0,
          "attributes": {
            "after": "[]",
            "comment": "Task to copy the MO messages from S3",
            "database": "ICEBERG",
            "enabled": true,
            "error_integration": "",
            "id": "ICEBERG|SRC|TASK_MO",
            "name": "TASK_MO_FNB",
            "schedule": "USING CRON 0 8 * * * UTC",
            "schema": "SRC",
            "session_parameters": null,
            "sql_statement": "COPY into ICEBERG.SRC.MO from (select $1,convert_timezone('UTC', current_timestamp)::timestamp_ntz,metadata$filename,metadata$file_row_number from @ICEBERG.SRC.MO (file_format =\u003e 'ICEBERG.SRC.GENERIC')) on_error=skip_file",
            "user_task_managed_initial_warehouse_size": "",
            "user_task_timeout_ms": null,
            "warehouse": "",
            "when": ""
          },
          "sensitive_attributes": [],
          "private": "bnVsbA==",
          "dependencies": [
            "snowflake_database.database",
            "snowflake_file_format.generic",
            "snowflake_schema.load_schemas",
            "snowflake_stage.all"
          ]
        },
```

The query that is being ran on Snowflake that (I guess) should identify the existing task. This query returns indeed zero items (which corresponds with the error message from Terraform).

```
SHOW TASKS LIKE '[]' IN SCHEMA "ICEBERG"."SRC"
```

Does anyone know what I can do to be able to update the task with Terraform?

Thanks, Chris

Comment: I don't know terraform at all, but it appears that you have an attribute of "after": "[]" in your code.  This seems to mean that there is a task that needs to run before this task that is named "[]".  The SHOW command that you've shared is trying to find that task, because in Snowflake, you can not modify any tasks if any of the parent tasks are active.  So, it's not liking that this task does not exist.  Can you remove the "after" parameter?  It makes no sense to have that when you have a SCHEDULE for this task.

Comment: This looks like an issue with the provider setting state attributes in the corresponding Create function in the resource schema. It may also be (less likely) an issue with the corresponding Read function. If your description in the question is accurate, then the most likely next step is filing an issue on the provider's tracker.

Comment: Thanks both! It makes sense I'll file an issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is reported here -  [Existing Task in plan & apply change & error #1071](https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/terraform-provider-snowflake/issues/1071). Upgrading the Provider Version to snowflake-labs/snowflake **0.37.0** should resolve the issue.